# When will the netfix prize be won?

Tags: netflix, prediction

Does anyone have a graph of the best [Netflix prize](http://www.netflixprize.com/) submission by day?  I'd like to get a prediction of when it will be solved based on extrapolating the existing progress.

Alternativly, when do you think it will be won and why?

Comment: what are you talking about?  Is this a programming question?  Links?

Comment: I've added a link to the post.  It is a challenge to develop an algorithm to do better than the Netflix movie suggestions.

Comment: I'm not convinced. If one of the other high-rep users wants to reopen this then feel free.

Comment: Well, I am powerless in this situation so do as you feel you must.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse [the leaderboard](http://www.netflixprize.com//leaderboard), then sort it by date, then calculate the daily maximum, etc. Personally, I do not believe such an extrapolation should give much, because you intend to predict the result of a complex process having many unknowns. [Here's a nice review of the contest from NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/11/23/magazine/23Netflix-t.html).

Comment: I thought about that, but the leaderboard only contains the best submission by each person (I think) and doesn't really give useful information about the best submission by each date.

I wouldn't expect an extrapolation to be very accurate, but I'm interested to see how it is trending.

Answer (score 0):

Contest begins October 2, 2006 and continues through at least October 2, 2011.
See [The Rules](http://www.netflixprize.com/rules)